# C# Linq nested class - where condition not work

Tags: c#, linq, join, nested

I have 3 entiy. I find category and join CategoryProduct,Product. 
it's work but "where p.IsActive == true" query is not work. 
I dont want join "p.IsActive == false"
What can I do?

```
var categoryQueryable = from c in context.Categories
                     where c.SeoUrl == seoUrl
                     join cp in context.CategoryProducts.ToList() on c.CategoryId equals cp.CategoryId
                     join p in context.Products.ToList() on cp.ProductId equals p.ProductId                                         
                     where p.IsActive == true
                     select c;


Category category = new Category();
category = categoryQueryable.FirstOrDefault<Category>();

public class Category
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SeoUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual List<CategoryProduct> CategoryProducts { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryProduct
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
 public classProduct
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual List<CategoryProduct> CategoryProducts { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: if you want to join only when Product is Active set to True. Then declare on top var product = context.Products.Where(m=>m.IsActive==true).tolist() .. Then use this declared variable inside your query join.

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, what does that literally mean? That could mean many things.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer. 
Result get now only active products.

```
 var categoryQueryable = from c in context.Categories
                         where c.SeoUrl.Trim() == seoUrl.Trim()
                         join cp in context.CategoryProducts.ToList() on c.CategoryId equals cp.CategoryId
                         join p in context.Products.Where(p => p.IsActive == true).ToList() on cp.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                         select c;
```